# Uniqueness of solutions for $ y^{\prime}(t)=(y-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \quad y(0)=y_0$ in he neighbourhood of $t=0$ for different values of $y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have bit confused of the problem:

Consider the initial value problem:
$$
y^{\prime}(t)=(y-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \quad y(0)=y_0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(A)
$$
Then, which of the following statements is/are true:

a. if $y_0=1,(A)$ has a unique solution in some neighbourhood of $t=0$.

b. if $y_0=1,(A)$ has more than one solution in some neighbourhood of $t=0$.

c. if $y_0=2,(A)$ has a unique solution in some neighbourhood of $t=0$.

d. if $y_0=2,(A)$ has more than one solution on the interval $(-1, \infty)$.

Attempt: I can say (b) is correct by taking the solutions $y=1$ and $y=\begin{cases} 1&t\leq 0,\\1+\frac{t^2}{4}&t>0, \end{cases}$ for $(A)$.

Doubt: Can we have more than two solutions valid in any neighbourhood of $t=0$?

Attempt: I can say (c) is correct by direct use of Picard's theorem since $f(t,y)=\sqrt{y-1}$ is locally Lipschitz w.r.t $y$ in some rectangle containing $(0,2)$. Also, we have $y=1+\frac{(t+2)^2}{4}$  as a solution for $(A)$ with $y_0=2$ in the interval $(-1,\infty)$.

Doubt: Can we find more than one solutions in the interval $(-1,\infty)$ whenever $y_0=2$? Of course, I got lot of solutions in the interval $(-1,\infty)$ whenever $y_0=1$ as $$y_c(t)=\begin{cases} 1&t\leq c,\\1+\frac{(t-c)^2}{4}&t>c, \end{cases},~c>0.$$

Comment: $f(y)=\sqrt{y-1}$ is not locally lipschitz in any neigborhood of $1$... So no chance to use Picard's theorem for the condition $y_0=1$.

Comment: Your second solution for (b) is wrong, as per the ODE, $y'$ can never be negative like $x/2$ is for $x<0$. The same goes for the second solution in case (d), as there $y'(x)=(x-2)/2$ with value $y'(0)=-1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks... I have corrected the things, Further, what about the uniqueness for $(A)$ whenever $y_0=2$ on the interval $(-1,\infty)$?

Comment: As long as $y>1$ you can apply Picard-Lindelöf and get uniqueness.

Comment: @LutzLehmann But Picard's uniqueness is in a neighbourhood of $t=0$, right? How can we extend the neighbourhood up to $(-1,\infty)$ unless the $f(t,y)=\sqrt{y-1}$ is Lipschitz in a vertical strip $(a,b) \times \Bbb R$?  Besides, even Picard's existence is not guaranteed in problems like $y'=y^2,y(0)=1$ while $f(t,y)=y^2$ is Lipschitz throughout $\Bbb R \times K$ for any compact set $K$, right?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I know that, Picard-Lindelöf provides the existence and uniqueness of solution for a problem $y'=f(t,y),~y(t_0)=y_0$ in an interval $(a,b),~-\infty \leq a<t_0<b\leq \infty$ whenever $f$ is Lipschitz w.r.t $y$ on $(a,b)\times \Bbb R$ (vertical infinite strip). Is it true if we have a semi infinite strip like $(,)×(1,∞)$ (as you said earlier)?

Comment: You already have existence via the solution formula. You only need the local uniqueness from P-L.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ya... I got it, thanks a lot..., and, what about my first doubt? I want to know whether more than two solutions ( other than those mentioned in the Attempt for $y_0=1) $valid in any nbd of $t=0$. Of course, I have uncountably many solutions of the form $y_c(t)=1$ for $t\leq c$ and $1+\frac{(t−c)^2}{4}$ for $t>c$, if we are fixing a nbd $(−h,h)$ and $0<c<h,$ but these distinct yc's become coincided if we decrease the size of the interval. right?

Comment: You have the first solution and $y=1$ branching off at $t=0$. There is no neighborhood small enough to remove this branching.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am not able to catch the point about branching of $y=1$. Can you make it clear for me?  Actually, I need a solution other than the already referred solutions $y=1$ and $y=\begin{cases} 1&t\leq 0,\\1+\frac{t^2}{4}&t>0, \end{cases}$ valid in any nbd of $0$.

Comment: This is correct. For any other solution you can make the neighborhood small enough so that its branching-off point is outside.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think you have a presupposition that the only possible solutions are of the form either $y=1$ or $y_c(x)$ as mentioned earlier, right? if so, how it is?